# Using Gallery.setSelection(position) during onCreate

Tags: android, gallery, selection

I'm creating an application that has a `Gallery`, and this `Gallery` has a different number of Views depending on orientation.  Broadly, some wide images are double-page spreads; as such they take up one `View` in landscape, but they are split to two Views (one per page) in portrait.

I have a system that remembers which "page" is selected and converts this to a position that can be sent to `Gallery.setSelection(position)`.  I'm calling this from `Activity.onCreate()`, using `Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` to pass the object holding this, among other, information back to the application.  Unfortunately `Gallery` then seems to be resetting itself to its previous position value after `onCreate` finishes.

Can I suppress this?  If not, when do I need to call my `Gallery.setSelection(position)` method?

Comment: I worked it out—it is necessary to call from onResume(), AFTER the call to super.onResume(), which is where the Gallery gets laid out.

Comment: There may be subtleties I have missed and if there are, please point them out :)

Comment: Hi Andrew Wyld have got the perfect solution for setposion of gallary view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out.

When the orientation changes, `Activity.onCreate()` is called and everything is inflated.  By overriding `Activity.onResume()` and calling Gallery.setSelection(position) with the desired value after super.onResume(), it is possible to get the correct behaviour; presumably the Gallery's selection is set to its previous value either during super.onResume() or in between Activity.onCreate() and `Activity.onResume()`.